# Regex with maximum 2 digits after the decimal point

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression that must take a valid only the numerical values with 0, 1 or 2 digits after the decimal point.

So I tried to do it like: `"^\\d+(\\.\\d){0,2}$"` but it returns true even for numbers with 3 digits after the decimal point.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Use `"^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?$"`

Comment: `/^\d+(\.\d){0,2}$/.test("3.142")` gives me `false` on my JavaScript console though.

Comment: `\b\d+\.\d{0,2}\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is saying "some digits, followed by 0-2 occurrences of a dot followed by a digit". Spot the mistake? `3.1.4` would match, but `3.14` wouldn't. Contrary to what you state in the question, 3 digits after the point wouldn't match either.

Instead, you would need something like this, assuming that the fractional part should be optional:

```
\d+(\.\d{0,2})?
```

Or, anchored and escaped for a string in your language of choice:

```
"^\\d+(\\.\\d{0,2})$"
```

Answer (score 4):

Your regex [`^\d+(\.\d){0,2}$`](https://regex101.com/r/DemkSv/1) matches `1` or `1.0` but also `1.0.0` because you specifiy a quantifier for 0-2 times for the group `(\.\d){0,2}` and would not match 3 digits after the dot.

To match a digit which could be followed by a dot and 1 or 2 digits after the dot you could use:

[`^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/G2kpRP/1)

Here the group after the first digit(s) is optional `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` and the quantifier is specified for the digit `\d{1,2}`.

Comment: Hi.. this: ^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$  is perfect for me but i want to allow also this: 0. or 1. or 2. or 3. and so on.
can you help me with this please?

Comment: @liron `^\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?$` https://regex101.com/r/DDZjVG/1